# PHP variable containing white space causing emails to fail

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

I am trying to send emails using the PHP mail function, but I am running into issues when it actually sends the email.

For some reason, the `$to` variable has a space between each character. So when it's emailed, the spaces are filled with dots.  The `$to` email is being grabbed from a TSV file generated from a remote system that I do not control.

I have seen where people have a line where it searches for white space and deletes it but i do not want to go that route.

The CC function works perfectly.

Does anyone know what may be happening? I have seen a couple of threads and bugs but they do not match it exactly.

```
 <?php
 $Name= $_POST["Name"];
 //File Upload Script
 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
 {
 }
 else
 {
  echo "File name: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:/xampp/htdocs/Uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "http://php/Uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
 $URLLink = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 //End File Upload Script

 //Reading TSV File
 $filename = $URLLink;

 //Deleting first line and last 5 lines
 $alines=file($filename);
 $dlines=array_slice($alines,1, -5);
 $fileContents=implode($dlines);
 $fp=fopen($filename,'w+');
 fwrite($fp,$fileContents);
 fclose($fp);  
 //END of Deleting first line and last 5 lines

$filename = $URLLink;
$file     = file($filename);

foreach($file as $line)
{
    list($start_time, $end_time, $instance, $status, $coordinator) = explode(" ", $line);

    $from = $SentFrom;
    $to   = $coordinator;
    $to = str_replace(' ', '', $coordinator);
    //$to = str_replace('.', '', $coordinator);
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:" . $from . "\r\n" . "CC:" . $mailer . "," . $emailone. "," . $emailtwo;
    $subject = "Test";

    include_once("EmailBody.php");

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

---

Page before is a form.

```
 <head>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
 <title>Impact Notification</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/menustyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <style type="text/css">
 .auto-style1 {
font-family: "Lucida Calligraphy";
 }
</style>
</head>
<body style="color: #black; background-color: #0000FF;">

<div align="center"id="MainWrapper" style="width: 70%">
<div id="container" style="width:100%">

<div id="PageHeader">
<?php include_once("../template/template_header.php");?>
</div>

 <div id="leftcolumn" style="height:auto;width:11%;float:left;padding:15px 15px 15px 15px;">
 <?php include_once("../template/menu.php"); ?>
</div>


<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:auto;width:80%;float:left;">
<h2 class="auto-style1">Email Notification</h2>
 <form action="sendemail.php" method="post" name="emails" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                            <td>Enter Your Name</td>
                            <td><input name="Name" type="text" style="width: 300px; height: 24px;" /></td>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 180px"><strong>File Upload:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /><input name="Clear" type="reset" value="Reset" /><br />
    <br />
</form>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: $to = str_replace(' ', '', $coordinator);

Comment: Is there no other way @Rottingham

Comment: Fix whatever is generating the TSV file so it doesn't include the extra characters.

Comment: @user3161708 There is, you could validate the input or what is giving you the funky string.

Comment: What does `$coordinator` contain?

Comment: I advise not to use PHP's mail function. It's prone to failure. I suggest using some mature and established mail classes such as PHPMailer

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat Surely you have evidence to support this bias?

Comment: @Rottingham - Ok. So I tried that but its still putting spaces which is causing the dots to appear in the to email

Comment: @Mave - $coordinator contains just an email address

Comment: @user3161708 Best thing to do is edit your question code so we can see how you implemented our suggestions.

Comment: @MikeW - I checked the TSV file, it does not contain any extra characters. I thought that was the cause, so I put in the email manually. Still not working

Comment: @user3161708 Its not white characters then, maybe new lines? http://ideone.com/dujK51

Comment: @Rottingham - I checked that in excel, its one cell, no lines after

Comment: What charset is the tsv file? Is it using a uble-byte character set?

Comment: @user3161708 update code. your missing something. if it is white space and you used str_replace(' ', '', $coordinator) it would work, or something else is messing it up

Comment: Here is a link to the tsv file https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BweGV79Rj0rxcWVhUjRscURtSmc/edit

Comment: @Rottingham - I have re-written the code from scratch twice. Still the same issue

Comment: You said the string had spaces in it, and dots were added after being introduced to mail() why did you use str_replace('.', '', $coordinator)? should be str_replace(' ', '', $coordinator); as suggested

Comment: @Rottingham - I was trying different things. The actual email does not contain spaces nor dots. In the actual code I also having it record everything into a db. db shows spaces (e x a m p l e @ e x a m p l e @ e x a m p l e . c o m)  but when I check the CC email it shows that its sending the email as e.x.a.m.p.l.e@e.x.a.m.p.l.e.c.o.m - I did try as suggested.

Comment: @Damien - Not sure. How can I tell?

Comment: Why are you defining that charset in your header? Maybe change that to UTF-8 or UTF-16? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp

Comment: @Damien - I was looking at a working code and was told I need that.

Comment: Maybe your main html page where you are reading your input from is not encoded with the same charset. Do you have some meta tag in your head there like <meta charset="UTF-8"> - perhaps that needs to change to match the charset you are defining above.

Comment: @Damien - I commented out the charset still getting the same results

Comment: @Damien - No html. The page is just PHP

Comment: Sorry, I mean the php page where the input is read.

Comment: Nope. No <meta> in the page

Comment: Have you tried adding one inside the head on that page that sets the charset to iso-8859-1?<meta charset="iso-8859-1">

Comment: @Damien - No, do I just put it after <?php I have never tried that in PHP

Comment: @Damien - Oh ya, that was in my header.

Comment: I don't think we can solve this without seeing your php input page section (the page that reads/processes the "to" field - I am assuming that this is generated from a user input field?) Maybe you could sanitise that and post it up in your question.

Comment: @Damien - Do you mean the page where the user uploads the file?

Comment: Wherever this $to variable is coming from....

Comment: The $to variable is coming from the TSV file. I will put the page before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revised Answer: BAD DATA HANDLING!**

Whilst it may still be a UTF / Charset issue, according to the code you have provided and sample data, your data handling is incorrect. Here are some tips for you (which have been incorporated into my suggested foreach loops below).

Your text file header contains a number of fields that you would like to retrieve. These are represented as the following fields sequentially in a row, separated by tabs:

`Start Time` `End Time` `Instance` `Type` `Status` `Endpoint` `Organizer` ....etc

You seem to be wanting a number of these fields to be captured, and amongst them, the $coordinator value needs to contain the data within the organiser field as listed within the text file (which appears to always be an email address):

1. Looking at your raw tsv file, your "list" processor is processing the wrong variables as you have missed the endpoint field!! Even if you're not going to use it, you'd need to put something in there for it to work the way you have set things up. At the very best, you would be storing the value for endpoint as $coordinator, but I suspect you wouldn't be getting that far because of the way you are exploding (see point 2 below).
2. The file you submitted seems to be separated by tabs, yet you're exploding using spaces. Change the " " in your explode to "\t". Currently, you're probably getting junk in your variable data (as it is splitting after every space in each line) - the organiser email address is not going to ever make it into $coordinator - perhaps you could echo your variables as a test to see what I mean (and comment out your mail function while you're testing).
3. I have revised your foreach loop:

   ```
   foreach($file as $line)
   {
       list($start_time, $end_time, $instance, $status, $endpoint, $coordinator) = explode("\t", $line); 

       $from = $SentFrom;
       $to   = $coordinator;
       $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
       $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
       $headers .= "From:" . $from . "\r\n" . "CC:" . $mailer . "," . $emailone. ","  .$emailtwo;
       $subject = "Test";

       include_once("EmailBody.php");   // Can' really comment on what's going on here - as I don't know what is in this file ! :)

       mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   }
   ```
4. You are stripping 5 lines from the bottom of the file and one from the top, but I see 6 lines that need to be removed from the bottom and one from the top in your sample file. Perhaps change the -5 to -6. Or alternatively, you could do something like this in your foreach loop to instruct the routine not to send an email if the $coordinator variable is "blank" so it doesn't fail if it reads a blank line, etc:

   **Alternative ForEach Loop - to stop blank lines within your file causing failures:**

   ```
   foreach($file as $line)
   {
       list($start_time, $end_time, $instance, $status, $endpoint, $coordinator) = explode("\t", $line); 
       if (trim($coordinator) !== '') 
       {
           $from = $SentFrom;
           $to   = $coordinator;
           $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
           $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
           $headers .= "From:" . $from . "\r\n" . "CC:" . $mailer . "," . $emailone. ","  .$emailtwo;
           $subject = "Test";

           include_once("EmailBody.php");   // Can' really comment on what's going on here - as I don't know what is in this file ! :)

           mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
       }
   }
   ```
5. You seem to be using a Windows implementation of PHP Mail. You may not have any issues with your current message content - just be aware that any lines starting with a period/fullstop will be removed. If you have any of your message lines starting with a '.', you might need something like this:

   ```
   $vardata = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $vardata);
   ```

Comment: hm. Then I am dead in the water. It is being exported from a server which I have no control over.

Comment: I'm creating this solution based on your code now and testing.. I'll let you know if I can reproduce/fix.

Comment: Thanks. I have to undo what I have done to the page because now I am getting that there is no specified "From" address :)

Comment: I have updated my answer based on my initial findings. Your data handling is not right. See my suggestions above.

Comment: Any luck with the suggestions?

Comment: Still not working. I am going to take a break from figuring this out and will start fresh tomorrow. Eyes are getting tired.

Comment: Ok. Well best of luck! Keep us posted. I am confident that based on the tsv file and code you have provided, until you fix up your data handling, you will never get the $to field working - it is getting the wrong data. I made the changes locally here, using everything you have provided and it all works here.

Comment: Your help was greatly appreciated. I used the second command where if the value is blank to not cause failures. You were right. The issue was with how I was reading the file. I changed the encoding from UCS-2 Little Endian to ASCII and it worked!

Comment: That's great! If you feel it has answered your question, perhaps you could consider marking the answer as accepted. :) Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a hex dump of the file, your data is encoded as UTF-16, which for ASCII data includes a `nul` character between each character of data. You can convert with `iconv()`

Note: you need to run this on the original file before you try extracting the data.

```
$str = file_get_contents('2.tsv');
$result = iconv($in_charset = 'UTF-16LE' , $out_charset = 'UTF-8' , $str);
if (false === $result)
{
    throw new Exception('Input string could not be converted.');
}
$result = substr($result, 3);      // Strip BOM
file_put_contents('3.tsv',$result);

echo $result;
```

Alternatively you can use

```
$str = file_get_contents('2.tsv');
$result = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'ASCII', 'UTF-16LE'); //instead of iconv()
file_put_contents('3.tsv',$result);
```

I have run both successfully on my development server.

Comment: When I tried that i got the followingNotice:
iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string in C:\xampp\htdocs\sendemail.php on line 69

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 501 5.1.3 8-bit character in mailbox address "<g$?g$?f??f??f ?f$?d??f??f$?g??f??f<?b8?f??f<?f4?>

Comment: I get the same. ¼€ã„€ã”€â¼€ãˆ€ã€€ã„€ã€â€€ã„€ã¨€ã€€ã€€à¤€ã„€â¼€ã„€ã˜€â¼€ãˆ€ã€€ã„€ã€â€€ã„€ã¨€ã when I echo

Comment: I've run both these on my development server using the file you provided a link to. If this is not working for you then there's more going on.

Comment: =/ 
 I just tried putting that $result line where I use array slicing and when the code reaches the point where it "explodes" the file I get the following. Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in C:\xampp\htdoc\sendemail.php on line 66

Comment: Guess what, you were right. It was something to do with the encoding. The TSV file is in UCS-2 Little Endian. I used the mb_convert_encoding command to convert it to ASCII. Once I did that, I stopped running into any issues!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `trim()`, to strip all sorts of whitespace characters only at the beginning and end of the string. I don't think I've seen it suggested yet.

https://www.php.net/trim

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will strip these characters:

```
" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
"\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
```

Comment: But this won't fix the issue of whitespace in the middle of the string.